# Playing a sound in IE on Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 device

Tags: asp.net, html, windows-embedded

I need to play a sound in an ASP.NET webapplication.

Currently I am using

```
<embed id="SoundPlaceholder" runat="server" src="/Audio/success.wav" hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="false" />
```

This works fine in IE on a desktop, however, when I run it in IE on a Windows Embedded device no sound plays.

**Operating System: Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5**

Does anyone know how I can solve this or is there another option for playing a simple short sound on a webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working, it turns out that `<embed>` is not supported on the device, nor is `<object>`.

```
<bgsound src="file://\windows\critical.wav" loop="1">
```

This will play the critical.wav sound file that resides on the actual device (therefore no need to download it).  You could however have specified a .wav file on the server as well.

Comment: hi! is there any way to add a "stop" button to terminate the sound? thanks!